# Sqoop mysql error - communications link failure

Tags: mysql, hadoop, bigdata, sqoop, sqoop2

Trying to run the below Command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://---.--.--.--:3306/home_credit_risk --table bureau --target-dir /home/sqoop --username root -password root;
```

I have Placed the mysql connector in the sqoop/lib folder and given permissions(755) to the connector jar to access it.

I am runnnig a AWS EMR service on which i have installed Sqoop Manually.

Getting the Below Error:

```
19/03/22 07:32:16 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
19/03/22 07:32:16 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
19/03/22 07:32:16 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
19/03/22 07:32:16 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
19/03/22 07:32:16 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:353)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2001)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:716)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:353)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.getInstance(Connection.java:295)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:904)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:763)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:786)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:289)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:260)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:246)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:327)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1872)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1671)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:106)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:501)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:628)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:168)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:262)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1926)
    ... 30 more
```

Any Pointer will be appriciated. Thankyou.

Comment: my Mysql Server is running on local machine and i am trying to acces the mysql using sqoop from AWS EMR Cluster .Source is local machine(MYSQL) and destination is AWS EMR.

Comment: Are you sure that the cluster can reach your local machine?

Comment: well i am new to hadoop technology ...i am not sure about that but on an assumption i suppose so that cluster can reach local machine using the ip

Comment: I think this is more a network issue than a hadoop related issue... first you have to be sure that your local machine and port are accessible from the internet.

Comment: yeah it was a Issue with the private ip as it cannot be accessed from outside network. Thanks @danielsepulvedab